# Azure Active Directory website redirect unexpected

Tags: c#, azure, owin, azure-active-directory

I have specified two URLs in my Azure Active Directory website configuration Reply URL. One to redirect to my localhost environment when I am running local code and one to redirect to my Azure hosted website when I am running the prod website. But Azure Active directory seems to be ignoring the setting. It only uses one or the other URL but not both
this is my startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;    

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.GivenName;

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,                    

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                                                
                    RoleClaimType = "roles"
                },

            });            
    }
}
```

and this my startup.cs

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);      
    }
```

and finally this is my web.config setting

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="*************************" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
<add key="ida:AppKey" value="******************************" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="****************************" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="url of production website" />
<add key="ida:Domain" value="company domain" />
</appSettings>
```

i dont know why this redirect occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem

you should add the following code in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions in Startup.Auth

```
               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Path);
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home", null, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Resource = GraphAPIIdentifier;                            
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }}
```

This way redirect uri is dynamically based on the machine you run it

Hope this be helpful.